# Повторное выполнение Runnable в потоке

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть класс `Worker` который содержит в себе очередь и при добавлении в очередь новой строки должен выполнить некую работу.

При создания потока в него передаеться `Runnable` который будет запущен после вызова метода `Thread.start()`. После этого в  `Worker` будут добавляться в очередь новые задачи через мтеод `.add()` и вот тут уже метод Runnable.run() будет вызван снова но уже в ручную.
**Вопрос**: меня интересует можно ли так делать, в смысле вызывать метод `.run()` вручную.
P.S.  в конструкторе потока я устанавливаю ему имя `Worker` но потом потом когда проверяю имя потока в `Runnable` то имя у него 'main', почему так происходит?

```
public class Worker {

    private static final String TAG = Worker.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final Log log = new Log(TAG);

    private static Worker instance;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> queryQueue;
    private WorkerThread workerThread;

    public static Worker getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Worker();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private Worker() {
        source = DBConnectionPool.getInstance().getSource();
        queryQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        workerThread = new WorkerThread(new Consumer(this.queryQueue));
        workerThread.start();
    }

    public void add(String s) {
        this.queryQueue.add(s);
        workerThread.execute();
    }

    class WorkerThread extends Thread {

        protected Consumer consumer;

        public WorkerThread(Consumer target) {
            this.consumer = target;
            //set thread name
            this.setName(this.getClass().getSimpleName()); //name is Worker
        }

        public void execute() {
            this.consumer.run();
        }
    }

    class Consumer implements Runnable {

        private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> queue;

        public Consumer(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread().getName(); // name is: 'main'
            //do simething
        }
    }
}
```

Добавляю элементы в очередь так:

```
Worker.getInstance().add("exampleString");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызывать метод run вручную не очень хорошо. Лучше сделать так чтобы Consumer сам отвечал за обработку поступающих строк.

ConcurrentLinkedQueue использует wait-free алгоритм и не блокирует поток, который достает элемент, если очередь пуста.

> This implementation employs an efficient "wait-free" algorithm based on one described in Simple, Fast, and Practical Non-Blocking and Blocking Concurrent Queue Algorithms by Maged M. Michael and Michael L. Scott.

Данная имплементация очереди обычно рассчитана на интенсивный обмен между производителем и потребителем данных. Также когда кол-во конкурирующих потоков велико.

Так как у вас только один worker вам будет лучше заменить ConcurrentLinkedQueue на [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) и использовать метод [take](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#take()). Этот метод будет блокировать worker-поток пока в очереди не появятся данные.

Comment: Спасибо, воспользовался вашим советом!